# Она, что, выглядела позавреча нехорошо / не хорошо?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Она, что, выглядела позавреча нехорошо / не хорошо?

> Юля некрасива / не красива?

> Георг и не умный, и не тупой / и неумный, и нетупой, по чьим-то словам.

> Нет! Я нетупой / не тупой!